# Signal is not connected - Godot

Tags: godot, gdscript

I am trying to implement a brightness slider into my game but am running into problems connecting the signal.

A global function is called, which should emit a signal.

```
extends Node

signal change_brightness(val)

func update_brightness(value):
    emit_signal("change_brightness", value)
    print(value)
```

The function successfully prints the value so the error is not to do with this.
The signal is connected to the below script.

```
extends WorldEnvironment

func _ready():
    GlobalSettings.connect("change_brightness", self, "_on_brightness_updated")

func _on_brightness_updated(value):
    print('hello')
    environment.adjustment_brightness = value # sets new brightness value
```

Hello is not being printed showing the signal is not working.

Thanks

Comment: Do you know that `connect` returns a value? It does. Output (`print`) what `connect` returns. Let us see if it is reporting an error. And if that does not print at all, it might be that the `connect` line is not running.

Comment: @Theraot Nothing is outputted when I printed the connect function. Any ideas why the connect line is not running?

Comment: I can only guess it is something with the scene setup. I presume the first script is an Autoload that goes by the name `GlobalSettings` that you use on the second script. And the second script is attached to a `WorldEnvironment` on the current scene. I fall as I can tell that should work. Is your setup different?

Comment: @Theraot That is exactly correct. The logic all seems correct, not sure why it is not working

Comment: The GlobalSettings Script is not connected to any node, would this make a difference?

Comment: You put a script or a scene as Autoload. If you put a script, Godot will give it a `Node`.  In fact if you add something like `func _ready() -> void: print(get_path())` to your Autoload script, it should output `/root/GlobalSettings`. I have now recreated the setup on my end and it seems to be working. Edit: Try doing this in a new project, perhaps you find out you skipped a step. Another idea that comes to mind: is pause involved? Perhaps the script that should `connect` to the signal is not running because the scene tree is paused.

Comment: I have recreated the setup in another project. Really not sure what I am doing that is making the signal not connect

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out.

The WorldEnvironment Scene was not instanced within the scene.

Knew it would be something silly.